# Strange behaviour upon reloading a page in iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, viewcontroller

In my `viewDidLoad` method I call a method `[self get_shcedule];`. This gets some values and stores in an array.

```
NSArray *filteredArray = [[jsonArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate] valueForKey:@"hour"];
```

In the same viewController I have an action define:

```
- (IBAction)update_schedule:(id)sender
```

which populates another array incase I wanted to update some of the values.

```
array2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

and `array2` is sent to same backend server with updated values.

In theory it all works fine, except I am getting a weird bug.

1. If I don't invoke the action, i.e., don't update the values and leave this particular page on my app. Upon return to this page everything works fine.
2. If I update the values by calling the action and leave the page and visit another page on my app, upon return to this page I get my values incremented by one.

From my understanding the `viewDidLoad` method is invoked every time a view is loaded if when we shift between pages on the same app.

Comment: add your code, your question is totally unclear to me.

Comment: How about viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear? Have you made some changes out there?

Comment: @KarthickRamesh no actually I deleted both viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear.

Comment: Can you please add the view controller code! Also what do you mean by “values incremented by one”?

Comment: You only get viewdidload when making a new controller and loading it into memory, not every time the view is loaded between pages say because you pushed and popped from the stack. (Effectively [foobarcontroller new]). I would suggest putting into view will appear. But I can’t debug without more info.